# soup.select returns empty list. Need help finding the source of the css code

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am currently going through the 'Automate the Boring Stuff' Udemy Course, lesson '40. Parsing HTML with the Beautiful Soup Module'. About  minutes in, Al uses requests the html of an amazon page and uses soup.select with the prices selector in order to print it out. I am currently trying to that with the exact same code, except for the usage of headers with seems to be necessary, otherwise i get a server error. I have read through some similar questions and the general solution seems to be to find the source for the data using the network panel. Unfortunately i have no clue on how to do that :/

```
import requests
import bs4
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome'}
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Automate-Boring-Stuff-Python-Programming-ebook/dp/B00WJ049VU/ref=tmm_kin_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=&sr='
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, features='html.parser')
print(soup.select('#mediaNoAccordion > div.a-row > div.a-column.a-span4.a-text-right.a-span-last > span.a-size-medium.a-color-price.header-price'))
```

Comment: Your question needs more clarification and please put a code sample in your question. We cannot help you till we see more of what you've done so far.

Comment: @AndréFradinho what's your desired output ?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη http://prntscr.com/rxsi09

Comment: @PatrickArtner I got five requests. Should I just go the 'trial and error' route or is there a way to find the particular element i need?

Comment: @AndréFradinho `22.86` is a value of what? it's not presented within that [page](https://www.amazon.com/Automate-Boring-Stuff-Python-Programming-ebook/dp/B00WJ049VU/ref=tmm_kin_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=&sr=)

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη It is the price of the item, in this case the book.

Comment: @AndréFradinho on my end it's ` $17.73 `

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I have selected the eBook version. Not sure whether it makes a difference but it was uniquely because it was sold and fulfilled by Amazon, not a third-party retailer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a more forgiving parser. You can also use a much shorter and more robust selector.

```
import requests
import bs4

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome'}
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Automate-Boring-Stuff-Python-Programming-ebook/dp/B00WJ049VU/ref=tmm_kin_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=&sr='
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, features='lxml')
print(soup.select_one('.mediaTab_subtitle').text.strip())
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm just wondering where you got '.mediaTab_subtitle'.

Comment: I see it in the html for page. I searched for price originally to see where it occurred.

Answer (score 0):

For better uses you can do `inspect element` and click on the top-left corner on the arrow icon and activate it. Then you can hover over the element and select. After selecting you can choose from copying `xpath`/`css selector`/`class`/`id`